# Failure start rails server Windows 7 x 64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7-x64

I'm starting to do some trials on rails. Today I'm trying to start the rails server but my Cmd throws this exception:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.2.1
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.2.1
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from D:/Datos/Dropbox/Desarrollo/AprendiendoRuby/Rails/MiPrimerRailsApp/
config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried to reinstall rails and run the bundle install too. I added a line in the GemFile, but I didn't get a solution.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Install `execjs` and `therubyracer` gems

Add the following to Gemfile

```
gem 'execjs'

gem 'therubyracer'
```

And then run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Vimsha, excuseme for this stupid question but, where is the Gemfile in windows; i saw that all the gems have Gemfiles?

Comment: It will be in your project root. For eg, if your rails project is `D://a` then your Gemfile will be in `D://a/Gemfile`

Comment: Hi Vimsha Thank you for all your answers.  When i try to add this elements to my gemfile y get a lot of news errors, that could be a bad installation?

Comment: Install the above gems in the same way you installed the other gems.

Answer (score 0):

First, `Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn available)`
Second, don't even try to use Windows for rails development, guard your health

Comment: Thank you antiqe for answer to me, but i try too run the "gem install execjs", but i get the same result.